# MySql find multiple rows with same value in a column

Tags: mysql, group-by

I record IP addresses in my DB and i want to look at accounts that have the same IP address as eachother. I'd like to show only results with more then one IP addresses. I preferentially would like it sorted by IP addressed used the most (IE if i have 30accounts with 127.0.0.1 as my ip i rather have that higher then 10ip address that belong to 192.168.1.123).

How do i write this query? I am using mysql

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT ip, COUNT(*)
FROM Table    
GROUP BY ip    
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1    
ORDER BY COUNT(*);
```